# Display user's default group without extension

Tags: phpbb3

I am using PHPBB 3.2.5 and I can't find any documentation regarding how to display a user's default group name (by code). I am currently modifying a theme and I want to display the user's default group name in a specific area.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer the question, if we don't have all the details, so I'm going to take some guesses... but first - **what specific area are you trying to display the group name?** It is already displayed on the viewprofile page of the memberlist. The variable you'd be interested in would be {L_USERGROUPS} I believe.

IE: 
/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=123

```
<!-- IF S_GROUP_OPTIONS --><dt>{L_USERGROUPS}{L_COLON}</dt> <dd><select name="g">{S_GROUP_OPTIONS}</select> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="{L_GO}" class="button2" /></dd><!-- ENDIF -->
```